# asp.net localized sitemap, bread crumb and menu

Tags: asp.net, localization, menu, sitemap, breadcrumbs

Here is what I want:

Site has 4 languages (Ch, Fr, It and En), everything is localized. I have CSS Friendly control adapters in place, so that I can use Superfish JQuery menu for navigation (other suggestions?). I want to somehow tie this menu, and the bread crumb to the localized sitemap.

My concerns:

1. Is it doable? Can you give me some suggestions / best practices?
2. How about SEO with sitemap localizations? I would like to have titles localized, so that menu and the bread crumb show proper names on different languages. I'm little concerned about SEO with all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works like a charm ... :)

I wont use ASP.NET sitemap for SEO, but instead I will generate a google-friendlier XML sitemap.